# Restart Guake inside Guake

Tags: bash, shell

Sometimes, after bad manipulations, Guake is stuck in full screen. I can use it, but it reduces greatly its practicallity.
I'm looking for a way to restart it while inside it.
I'd like to do :

```
at now + 5 seconds guake & ; pkill -f guake
```

Which would work fine if

```
at
```

supported seconds. Unfortunately it doesn't so I'm forced to launch another type of terminal, kill guake, and restart it.

If anyone has an idea, that'd be most welcome !

Comment: Perhaps you can use `screen`, `tmux`, or `byobu` (if on Ubuntu) inside of Guake, then the parent PID will belong to one of those emulators instead of your Guake session, and the children PID's won't die when you issue `pkill`. I havent' tested, but it seems reasonable as a quick fix.

Comment: Tried with screen just now. Unfortunately it doesn't work but I like the idea  of a different PID. I'll dig deeper into the idea

Answer (score 1):

> Disclaimer: This answer works, but still needs a manual input. **I'm seeking help** to create a one-liner script.

This is possible if you **kill and respawn `guake` from another terminal** (here `gnome-terminal`).
The trick is to start this second terminal from `guake` itself, without having it crash when you kill `guake`.

Here how to do it:

1. in `guake`:

   ```
   screen -dmS other_terminal gnome-terminal
   ```

   1. opens a new window,
   2. start `gnome-terminal`,
   3. detach the window.

   This is done using `screen`. The `-dms` flag create a deamon — you can set its name (here `other_terminal` to whatever) you want.
2. then, in the now created `gnome-terminal` instance:

   ```
   pkill -f guake; screen -dmS guake_respawn bash --login -c "guake; exec sh"; exit
   ```

   1. kill `guake` (via `pkill`),
   2. opens a new window
   3. start `guake` (you don't want to only run `guake`, but also make is continue when you close the window. Hence running `guake; exec sh` via `bash`.)
   4. detach the window (via `screen -dmS`)
   5. close `gnome-terminal` (`exit`)

---

The current **issue** is that **I cannot successfully pass commands to the created `gnome-terminal` instance** prior I detach the window.